# How to convert a DGN file (shared cells) into a DWG file (AutoCad blocks) in FME?

Tags: autocad, fme, microstation

Me and my colleague are currently trying to convert a DGN file (with many points) into a realDWG file. The DGN file is roughly 90 MB, since there are shared cells in the DGN file. Shared cells are elements that are stored only once in the DGN file, regardless of how often the cell is placed within the DGN file. This makes it possible to have a relatively small size for the DGN file. However when I simply connect the DGN reader and the DWG writer together, the filesize of realdwg is roughly 600MB! Apparently shared cells are during the translation to realdwg treated as an autoblock in itself, while I would like to have the same capacity in the realdwg that there is only one autoblock and the the others are referencing to that one autoblock, however still visually shown  which ideally should make the realdwg smaller. Does anyone know if that can be achieved in FME?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a DWG file to DGN format.

Steps:
1-Open the DWG file in MicroStation using File > Open

2-From Menu bar, Choose File > Save As.

3-Use [Save as type:] drop down and change to: Autodesk DWG Files (*.DWG)

4-Click [Options] and change desired settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNHcB.png

For Unsupported Dimension

-set "ON"

-Drop Unsupported Dimensions (from Advanced" Tab)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROKD6.jpg

5. Click Save.

Comment: Thank you, but instead of doing it in Microstation or Autocad, in order to automate, I would like to the transformation in FME.